# Get first item from nested list in glom

Tags: python, glom

```
from glom import glom, T

target = {
    "items": [
                {
                    "label": "valuation",
                    "value": [
                        "900 USD"
                    ]
                },]
}
spec = ('items',[T['value'][0]])
r = glom(target,spec)
print(r)
```

The above code returns a list, `['900 USD']` but I'd like to just get the content of that list, i.e the first item in the 'value' list. In this case the result should just be `900 USD`

## Part 2

```
from glom import glom, T, Check, SKIP

target = {
    "items": [
                {
                    "label": "valuation",
                    "value": [
                        "900 USD"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": "other_info",
                    "value": [
                        "700 USD"
                    ]
                },]
}
spec = ({
    'answer': ('items', [Check('label', equal_to='valuation', default=SKIP)],([T['value'][0]]))
})
r = glom(target,spec)
print(r)
```

The above code results in `{'answer': ['900 USD']` but I need to just return `900 USD`.
Tried adding `[0]` at the end of the brackets but that didn't work.
Playing around with the `T` type also didn't result in what I'm looking for

Comment: Do you mean r[0]?

Comment: or `r = glom(target,spec)[0]`

Comment: @NiekdeKlein thanks. r[0] works.
My original problem is a little more complex than I've posted but this gives me some insight on how to proceed

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by iterating over my result list and picking out the first element.
The following spec worked

```
spec = ({
    'answer': ('items', [Check('label', equal_to='valuation', default=SKIP)],( [T['value'][0]] ,Iter().first()) )
})
```

Notice the `Iter().first()` function call was added.

Answer (score 1):

```py
spec = {
    'answer': ('items', Iter().filter(
        lambda x: x['label'] is 'valuation'
    ).map('value.0').first())
}
```

Note, this is a streaming solution, thus performing better for larger datasets.

A string spec -- here `'value.0'`, the argument to the `map` method -- understands indexing into deep lists.

Depending on the specific logic that is desired this might work as well:

```py
spec = {
    'answer': ('items', Iter().first(
        lambda x: x['label'] is 'valuation'
    ), 'value.0')
}
```

Here, we have combined filter logic with the restriction of a single result.